# How to use a Hambleton Bard s30 cylinder?

Tags: carbonation, pressure, gas

I've recently purchased a second hand (hence no instructions) pressure barrel keg that has an s30 adaptor that fits a Hambleton Bard cylinder (which I have also bought).

How do I actually use this though?  Do I screw it on and leave it there or just give a blast for a second?  How is the pressure controlled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used one myself, but the cylinder is at 800 psi.  So you'd only want to give it short burps, especially on more full keg.  Once you thread the cylinder onto the S30 fitting, continue turning to start gas flow and unscrew to stop the flow.

Pressure would then be manually-controlled, like a keg pump (minus spoiling your beer).  Several manufacturers do make a version with a regulator and a short hose that you connect to a gas fitting (ball-lock and pin-lock like on the top of a Corny keg), but I don't think the fitting on the regulator accepts your S30 cylinder.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control the pressure with any accuracy, as it's a case of screw it in, give it a squirt and then unscrew it. If you put too much in, then the pressure relief valve should allow the excess to escape. One thing you'll want to do, as your cask is second hand, is replace the seals, especially the one on the pressure relief valve.

If you want to control the pressure with any accuracy, then you need to get a proper gas setup, like the Widget World stuff -> http://www.homebrewcentre.co.uk/categories.asp?cID=143